# Inline CSS stripped from Global: Custom text in Views

Tags: 7, views

I did some research on the problem in the title but haven't found any good solutions yet.

I'm using a Global: Custom text view field in a view and I need inline CSS to work in there.

I know that it gets stripped because security reasons, and I *have to* use inline CSS for my problem. So "use CSS classes" is not a solution, I'm well aware that in most cases that would be the best but it's not ok in this case.

Writing a node.tpl.php for the content instead of using a view in Fields mode is also not possible, becaue I have to use view result counter token on the same div where my inline css should go (with another token inside the inline css).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not wise but use a custom PhP field : [Views PhP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) *(it's "Views custom field if you're on D6)*.

Comment: Already tried that with the output code <?php print $row->nothing ;?> (where $row->nothing is my custom text field with all the markup and tokens I need) but it's empty. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: yeah it's always empty, use $data instead of $row. If you need to know what's inside $data, use a dpm($data); in your php field.

Comment: I've found no sign of my custom text field in $data, but I see all the other view fields.

Comment: Did you add your field ? You have to add and hide it before the php field.

Comment: Yes, I added the Views PHP field after the custom text field. The PHP field is the last in the order.

Comment: Oh I get it, your "custom field" is only in the view, not on the content type. Ok, so everything you have in your custom field, you have to set it in the php field, not **re-use it** in the php field. Only use this field.

Comment: I see. I can't use the tokens in the PHP field, so I'm guessing I should construct the same thing with variables like $data.

Comment: Another problem, I can't find the view result counter in any of the available variables.

Edit: found the soludion for the view result count http://drupal.org/node/1354024#comment-5828588

Comment: Maybe just <img src=" ?